# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for some tables when using high ResultSet.fetchSize()

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

I'm using ojdbc-11.2.0.4 drivers to connect to an Oracle 11g database and extract data. For a few tables When I do a setFetchSize to 100000 on the ResultSet I get the following stack trace. This doesn't happen for all the tables just some of them.
If I reduce the fetch size to say, 10000, this error goes away. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -184134849   
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.saveDataFromOldDefineBuffers(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:416)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.saveDefineBuffersIfRequired(T4CStatement.java:536)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareAccessors(OracleStatement.java:1078)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.check_row_prefetch_changed(OracleStatement.java:3087)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:332)
```

Comment: these some tables have less 100000 rows and in this table

Comment: First try the latest Oracle JDBC driver to see if it still occurs, otherwise report it as a bug to Oracle.

Comment: No Ahmed, they have much more than that.